# Laravel Passport and Firebird

Tags: php, laravel, firebird, laravel-passport, last-insert-id

I'm working with an application in Laravel 5.5 with Firebird database. I'm trying to install Laravel Passport, but when I do php artisan passport:install I get error:

> "In Processor.php line 34
>
> SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does
> not support lastInsertId()"

I know that Firebird doesn't support `lastInsertId` and in my models I changed the increment value to false to get it working, but I don't know how to fix it in Passport to get the package installed and working. I've searched here and in other forums but didn't found a similar case or any fixes.

Comment: Firebird does have the equivalent of lastinsertid with `insert .. returning ..`, it is probably not supported in the driver for Laravel. You may want to see who maintains that driver and file an improvement for that.

Comment: Also, w.r.t. `support auto increament.` - Firebird does support auto-incrementing, though it might take some boilerplate to do it before Firebird 3, where auto-inc shortcut datatype was introduced

Comment: I wrote an issue for the driver but noone answered yet, looks a little forgotten. Tried to hardwire the Processor.php code but Passport didn't installed property so it don't work. Idk if someone else tried to use Passport against a Firebird db.